# scrollToItemAtIndexPath Crash for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In `UICollectionView` whenever trying to jump to an index using function call `scrollToItemAtIndexPah` the app is crashing sometime with the following exception.

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   -[__NSCFNumber frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbaddad2c1713bead

Not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: can you share your code how you are getting indexpath .?

Answer (score 0):

this error
[__NSCFNumber frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbaddad2c1713bead

comes when you are having a number and you are trying to access the frame value on the number object

For example : you might get this error when you do

```
[3 frame];
```

or

```
NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2];
[number frame];
```